# Problem starting a PPA: apt refuse to connect with my PPA

Tags: 18.04

I created my own PPA onto an external drive with an ext4fs and a gpt file alocation table to store all of my updates. Working with gparted, the standard rights where: owner=root, group=root. So I created all tree files: Packages.gz, Release, Release.gpg with the administrator rights (sudo). Every thing worked fine. Then, I opened software & update to add the repository and the signing key to apt. Once your done and clic "close", apt proceed to an automatic repository refresh and the problem is write there. apt tells me something like this: performed outside the sandbox as root... and also apt tells me that there is no Release. The directory repository is: /media/?user/?partition/allpackage
Packages.gz Release Release.gpg.
Now I need some help to understand and fix this technical problem. OS:Gnu/Linux-Ubuntu 18.04.4
Thanks
From: Peter